# Custom Wrapper Exception In Java-7 Vs Multi-Catch

Tags: java, exception, java-7

What's the difference between a wrapper exception and the multi-`catch` statement they have. Aren't they the same and I can use the multi-`catch` instead of build up my own exception and in it wrapper?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Your question is not clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing 2 concepts. The multi-catch is a convenient way of saying here is the code for handling these conditions. It just provides a more terse version of older code. Whereas wrapping an exception allows for you to provide your callers with a more meaningful exception - this is a question of how you design your application. For example, I have worked on applications in the past that chose to wrap all data access exceptions in a DAOException. The caller knows generally something went wrong and can act accordingly. They can also look inside to see the specifics if needed.

Comment: oka you right and i get that right now but if i  wrote this code and am the only one knows how it goes can i use the multi-catch instead of the wrapper ?!! and if that right so that's all i need to be sure about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Good pracice is to avoid creation of custom exceptions when you have standard one that serves exactly the same purpose. But more important thing is that wrapping method calls with your one code can make you code less readable. Moreover, trowning new exceptions is a resource-consuming operation!

Also, some block of code can throw exceptions that are very different by nature. It is not very wise idea to theat them as something similar, even if the exception handling is similar in your case.